# MySql Slave, how to check if it is used

Tags: mysql, database-performance, master-slave

I've configured a master-slave replication and everything seems working properly and the slave is running with 0 seconds behind master. Now I want to remove the word "seems".

I'd expect to have a gain in reads, but if I execute a heavy query on Master nothing happens on the slave as if it's not used and I'm saying this because the load is 0, connections are not increased, selects per seconds are 0 and innodb reads per seconds are 0 (data from mysql workbench).

Did I miss anything on the config side? How can i properly test this?

Comment: why do you think that execution of the query on master should affect slave at all?

Comment: you can expect gain only if your application logic distribute read queries across databases, so half of the queries will execute on master, half on the slave

Comment: Or send all reads to the slave except for those needed to support writes.  And also send 'critical reads' to the Master.

Comment: I wrongly thought that mysql replication was an "automated" process: the master would be aware of existings slaves and redirect loads between the structure... Thank you guys, I'll redirect reads on the slave db and writes on the master!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to check if slave is used...

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
```

This will have some increasing numbers that indicate that data is flowing to the Slave.  (OK, that was not part of the question, but it is important.)

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Com%';
```

This will show how many Selects, Updates, etc, etc, have been performed on the machine where it is run.  Perhaps of most interest is `Com_select`.  If that is 0, you have not had any reads.  If that is 'small', it might be due to various other things, such as monitoring scripts.

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used%';
```

`Max_used_connections` gives the high-water-mark for connections.  If it is only `1`, that does not prove anything.  If it is higher, there *probably* you had multiple real connections doing *real* work.

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

If it only shows yourself, not good.  If it shows some `Sleep` threads, then that could be leftover connections that are doing nothing at the moment, but have not disconnected yet -- good.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the variables! My problem, as explained above, is that I wasn't actually using the slave for the reads... but this commands will help me monitoring the situation